# Multiple Memory Arguments to processbuilder is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory

I created a runnable jar file which needs to run on users' machines. Because my application needs a lot of memory, I use a `ProcessBuilder` to specify the memory arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String path = System.getProperty("java.home")
            + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = 
            new ProcessBuilder(path, "-Xmx1024m", "-cp",
                    classpath, 
                    myclass.class.getName());

    Process process = processBuilder.start();
}
```

This `1024` is working fine when I run through Eclipse. When I execute it directly from the jar file, it throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. Any clues?

Comment: how do you start this main ?..

Comment: Process process = processBuilder.start(); this will start the main method

Comment: No, the one you described, how is the first main started ? with eclipse you click on the play button or something, but once it's a jar, you double click it ? Or you call it with from a cmd terminal/linux shell ?

Comment: I Double click it run.

Comment: Mhh, not sure if the arguments are correctly passed from a JVM through another. For your specific problem, try printing `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();` from both programs. For a more general matter, why don't you use the command line to start your program and use cmd line arguments directly ?